# Creating an SQL query from a dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dictionary

I have a function to update an entry in a database (MySQL) and it needs to be as dynamic as possible.

The function allows the user of the API to pass an id of a record and then kwargs to handle the values to change (there is no limit on how many values can be passed).

So lets say I get this dictionary from kwargs

```
{'hello':'world', 'foo':'bar'}
```

Is there a way I can use this in an update statement.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET key_n = val_n, key_n+1 = val_n+1, ...
WHERE id = the_id_passed_to_the_function
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def UpdateQuery(data,where):
    if isinstance(data, dict) and where:
        vals = ','.join(["%s=?" %(k) for k,v in data.iteritems()])
        query = "update myTable set %s where id=?" % (vals)
        res = cr.execute(query,where)
```

Comment: For Python 3, use `data.items()` instead of `data.iteritems()`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foo = kwargs['bar']
id = 1
if foo:
    k = foo.keys()
    q = '''UPDATE myTable'''
    q += ','.join('SET {0}=%s'.format(i) for i in k)
    q += 'WHERE id = %s'
    cur.execute(q,tuple(foo[i] for i in k)+(id,))
```

Some points to note:

1. Since dictionaries are unordered, we are fetching a list of the keys first.
2. Instead of putting the values directly in the query; you should pass them in. Again, we step through the same list of keys so that the values match the column names.
3. Finally, we add the id to the set of ordered arguments to the query.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Python 3

```
def sql_update_from_dictionary(self, update_table, update_dict, update_id):
    """
    UPDATE query from dictionary
    Args:
        update_table (str): Name of the table
        update_dict (dict): Data to be updated
        update_id    (str): id of the item that will be updated
    """
    sql = "UPDATE "+update_table+" SET {} WHERE id=".format(', '.join('{}=%s'.format(k) for k in update_dict))+str(update_id)
    db.execute(sql, list(update_dict.values()))
    connection.commit()
```